# Best way to get a param into DoFn's onElement method in Apache Beam

Tags: apache-beam

I need to pass a param from the Main to my DoFn method to be used by onElement method. Below is the example in code.

```
public class MyPTransformClass<T> extends PTransform<PCollection<elemCLass>, PDone> {

@Override
public PDone expand(PCollection<elemClass> input) {
    input.apply(ParDo.of(new Fn<>()));
    return PDone.in(input.getPipeline());
}

private static class Fn<T> extends DoFn<elemClass, String> {

    private Fn() {
    }

    @Setup
    public void onSetup() {
      
    }

    @ProcessElement
    public void onElement(final ProcessContext context) {
        //Do some transformation using a PARAMETER passed from outside
    }
}
```

}

I was wondering how can I pass the PARAMETER above to my DoFn without using ***side_input***. This is not dynamic and will be staying the same throughout the entire execution.

I tried passing it to **MyPTransform** and then access it from within the DoFn, but it always ends up being Null in DoFn.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a property which is passed to the DoFn in the constructor.

If this is a parameter that is available in the pipeline options, then you can read that value in the expand of the PTransform.

```
private static class Fn extends DoFn<elemClass, String> {

int something;

    public Fn(int something) {
    this.something = something
    }

    @Setup
    public void onSetup() {
      
    }

    @ProcessElement
    public void onElement(final ProcessContext context) {
        //Do some transformation using a PARAMETER passed from outside
        use something
    }
}
```